# Sum values in third column while putting together corespondinng values in first and second columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have 3 columns of data.  I have data stored in three columns (k, v, t) in csv. For instance,

Data:

```
k v t    

a 1 2    
b 2 3    
c 3 4    
a 2 3    
b 3 2    
b 3 4    
c 3 5    
b 2 3
```

I want to get as the following data. Basically, sum all the values of t that has the same k and v.

```
a 1 5
b 2 6
b 3 6
c 3 9
```

this is the code I have so far:

```
aList = []
aList2 = []
aList3 = []

for i in range(len(data)):
    if data['k'][i] == 'a':
        if data['v'][i] == 1:
            aList.append(data['t'][i])
        elif data['v'][i] == 2:
            aList2.append(data['t'][i])
        else:
            aList3.append(data['t'][i])
```

and it keeps going until the end.

I use "for loop" and "if" but it is too long. Can I use numpy in a short and clean way? or any other better way?

Comment: In what form do you have the data stored? You're using it as a dictionary consisting of k,v,t as keys and their corresponding values as lists, but using `len(data)` to get the range, which is a bit confusing. Post the data structure in the question.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar. I have data stored in three columns (k, v, t) in csv.

Comment: Please add that in the question for future viewers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution using `pandas`.

First create a dataframe, then perform a `groupby` operation. The below code assumes your data is stored in a csv file.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

g = df.groupby(['k', 'v'], as_index=False)['t'].sum()
```

**Result**

```
   k  v  t
0  a  1  2
1  a  2  3
2  b  2  6
3  b  3  6
4  c  3  9
```

Comment: @CullenDuYaw. It is indeed possible without pandas, but I would challenge the criteria for considering it "better".